# ng-bind-html not displaying until click of anchor tag or ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little method that computes user rating average and outputs it as a visual representation to the user.

The problem I'm running into is the method's results for both `rating` and `rateDisplay` aren't displayed until I click on an anchor tag or executing an ng-click. I can't figure out why, as the method and any anchor tag/ng-clicks are completely independent of each other. I've tried logging to make sure it's executing when I want it to and it is. Before, when I was using handlebars, I didn't have any problems displaying the visual representation with the triple bracket escaping. But since moving to Angular, I'm having problems with this. I have included `ngSanitize` as a dependency.

**quickblox.js**

```
    listRatings: function(names, businesses) {
            var data = { _parent_id: names };

            QB.data.list("Comments", data, function(err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    // console.log("There was an error: " + err);
                } else {
                    console.log('ok we start nao');    // confirm we execute when we need to
                    var comps = {};

                    for (var i=0, len=result.items.length; i<len; i++) {
                        if (!comps[result.items[i]._parent_id]) {
                            comps[result.items[i]._parent_id] = [];
                        }
                        comps[result.items[i]._parent_id].push(result.items[i]);
                    }

                    for (var name in names) {
                        if (!(names[name] in comps)) {
                            for (var business in businesses) {
                                if (businesses[business].id == names[name]) {
                                    businesses[business].rating = '';
                                    businesses[business].rateDisplay = '  No comments yet, be the first!'.substr(1);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            var sum = 0;

                            for (var j=0, len=comps[names[name]].length; j<len; j++) {
                                sum += parseInt(comps[names[name]][j].rating);
                            }

                            var avg = sum/comps[names[name]].length;

                            var avgFinal = 0;

                            if (avg.toFixed(1) % 1 === 0) {
                                avgFinal = avg + '/5';
                            } else if (avg.toFixed(1) % 1 !== 0) {
                                avgFinal = avg.toFixed(1) + '/5';
                            }

                            var needsHalf = (avg.toFixed(1) % 1);

                            var fullRating = '';

                            for (var k=0; k<5; k++) {
                                if (k < Math.floor(avg)) {
                                    fullRating += '<span class="icon-circle"></span>';
                                }
                                else if (needsHalf) {
                                    fullRating += '<span class="icon-half"></span>';
                                    needsHalf = false;
                                }
                                else {
                                    fullRating += '<span class="icon-none"></span>';
                                }
                            }

                            for (var business in businesses) {
                                if (businesses[business].id === names[name]) {
                                    businesses[business].rating = avgFinal;
                                    businesses[business].rateDisplay = fullRating;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**results.js**

```
    $scope.businesses = [];
    $scope.results = [];       // didn't show how I populate this, not necessary 
    var names = [];

    // grab data to be applied to $scope.businesses
    getData.getBusinesses()
        .then(function(data) {

            var tempBusinesses = data,
                tempConditionData;

            for (var business in tempBusinesses) {

                tempConditionData = tempBusinesses[business].conditionData;

                for (var condition in tempConditionData) {
                    if (tempConditionData[condition].id === $scope.results.id && tempConditionData[condition].published === true) {
                        names.push(tempBusinesses[business].id);
                        $scope.businesses.push(tempBusinesses[business]);
                    }   
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function() {
            quickblox.listRatings(names, $scope.businesses);
        })
        .then(function() {
            $scope.dataLoaded = true;
        }, 
        function(err) {
            $log.log('something went wrong: ' + err);
        });
```

Lastly,

**results.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="business in businesses | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
    <td class="4u provider-info">
        {{business.name}} 
        <br> 
        <span ng-bind-html="business.rateDisplay"></span> <small>{{business.rating}}</small> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've also ran a JSHint several times and I'm not coming up with any errors. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

As per requested, here's my code for `getBusinesses()`

```
appData.factory('getData', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
    'use strict';

    var baseURL = 'http://someapiurl.com/';

    return { 
        // ...
        getBusinesses:function() {
            return $http.get(baseURL + 'businesses')
                .then(function(res) {
                    if (typeof res.data === 'object') {
                        return res.data;
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject(res.data);
                    }
                },
                function(err) {
                    return $q.reject(err.data);
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for getBusinesses()?

Comment: Also, is QB.data.list("Comments", data, function(err, result)).... an async call?  Does

Comment: Updated question and yeah, quickblox performs everything asynchronously. Admittedly, QB isn't the way I would have preferred going, but due to budgetary constraints I have to make do with it.

Comment: Then the current answer given should solve your issue.  Just wrap the code called by the QB.data.list callback function in a $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without fully knowing what is going on under the covers, I'm going to take a guess that you have an async operation happening outside of the "Angular-world". In other words, Angular is not aware that a change to a scope-exposed variable has happened and a digest cycle is not triggered, until you have clicked on a button with `ng-click`, for example, that triggers a digest.

The likely place where it is happening is here:

```
QB.data.list("Comments", data, function(err, result) {

});
```

This is an async operation, correct? With the handler function invoked on completion?

If you assign anything to the scope variable there, it would not be visible to Angular, unless you invoke `$scope.$apply`. Let's assume you factored out the current handler function as `yourCurrentHandler`:

```
function yourCurrentHandler(err, result){
   // whatever you do right now
   // ...
}

QB.data.list("Comments", data, function(err, result) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){ 
      yourCurrentHandler(err, result); 
   }); 
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EMRjt8xN9vTT6lCaao1H?p=preview) with an illustrative example

Comment: Perfect! Right now my QB stuff is held in a factory, I think I need to change that so I can properly use your answer, but I'll do some more research into it. Still pretty new to Angular, so thanks for dumbing it down to where I can understand what's happening.

Comment: Actually, yeah. I just used $rootScope (please correct me if this is the wrong way) and all seems to be working great now. Thanks a ton, you are a god among mere mortals.

Comment: It would work, yes - but I would separate Angular and non-Angular worlds, by creating a `$q` wrapper around the non-Angular async operation and abstracting it away in a service. It keeps the controller clean: http://plnkr.co/edit/OCKhs6hyfhWSO44UFdZy?p=preview

Comment: Noted, I'll give that a go too. Definitely prefer as clean of a controller as possible.